# Aggregate and grouping in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

How do I get a summary count in Mongo. I have the following record structure and I would like to  get a summary by date and status

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "History": [
    {
      "id": "11",
      "message": "",
      "status": "send",
      "resultCount": 0,
      "createdDate": "",
      "modifiedDate": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "message": "",
      "status": "skipped",
      "resultCount": 0,
      "createdDate": "",
      "modifiedDate": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I would like..

```
 date x

    status : 

    count : nn
```

This is my Mongo structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have the following data in 'history' collection:

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "History": [
    {
      "id": "21",
      "message": "",
      "status": "send",
      "resultCount": 0,
      "createdDate": "date1",
      "modifiedDate": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "22",
      "message": "",
      "status": "skipped",
      "resultCount": 0,
      "createdDate": "date1",
      "modifiedDate": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "message": "",
      "status": "skipped",
      "resultCount": 0,
      "createdDate": "date2",
      "modifiedDate": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "message": "",
      "status": "skipped",
      "resultCount": 0,
      "createdDate": "date2",
      "modifiedDate": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

You can design your query in the following way to get the desired summary.

```
db.history.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$History"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":{
                "createdDate":"$History.createdDate",
                "status":"$History.status"
            },
            "createdDate":{
                $first: "$History.createdDate"
            },
            "status":{
                $first:"$History.status"
            },
            "count":{
                $sum:1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$createdDate",
            "createdDate":{
                $first:"$createdDate"
            },
            "info":{
                $push:{
                    "status":"$status",
                    "count":"$count"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

It would result in the following:

```
{
    "createdDate" : "date1",
    "info" : [
        {
            "status" : "skipped",
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "status" : "send",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    "createdDate" : "date2",
    "info" : [
        {
            "status" : "skipped",
            "count" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Aggregation stages details:

- Stage I: The 'History' array is unwinded i.e. the array would be split and each element would create an individual document.
- Stage II: The data is grouped on the basis of 'createdDate' and 'status'. In this stage, the count of status is also calculated.
- Stage III: The data is further grouped on the basis of 'createdDate'
  only
- Stage IV: Eliminating non-required fields from the result